# Undefined class 'StorageTaskSnapshot'. Try changing the name to the name of an existing class or creating a class with the name 'StorageTaskSnapshot'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to upload a photo to the firebase. When I tried to use StorageTaskSnapshot it makes underline StorageTaskSnapshot saying Undefined class 'StorageTaskSnapshot'.

This is my code:

```
Future<String> uploadPhoto(img) async {
    UploadTask task =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Posts Pictures").child("post_$postId.jpg").putFile(img);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot =await task.onComplete;
    String downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }
```

Anyone Please Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
TaskSnapshot uploadFile = await child("Posts Pictures").child("post_$postId.jpg").putFile(img);
  if (uploadFile.state == TaskState.success) {
            final String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
         }
```

First get the reference to the firebase storage instance, then using `putFile()` you can upload the file to the storage which also returns a `TaskSnapshot`. After that if the state of the uploaded file is success then get the downloaded url.

Comment: Yeah that might work. But I solved the problem just by adding whenComplete method
Like that :

TaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot=
        await task.whenComplete(() => null)